# command line with regular expressions java

Tags: java, regex, string, command-line

Sorry for my English. How to pass arguments to the command line that used for example if I write the word in quotation marks "something" I find it a regular expression, and if the word without quotation marks nothing.
That's how I thought about do it. But this is not correct and not nice.

```
if(args[0].charAt(0) == ' " ' && args[0].charAt(args[0].length()-1) == ' " ') {
                System.out.println("Regular");
            }
```

Comment: You can't. The shell will remove the quotes so there is no way of telling from within Java whether they were ever present.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `'\"'` when you check for it, and use `'"somestring"'` in the command line (single quote to mark args

Also works for `'"some string"'` (works with spaces)